# "Expected:=" compile error in vb6 while adding recordset to SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: vb6, data-access

Here I created recordset in vb6 and store values in that vb6. i want to write that recordset values to database table. while executing that code i am getting compile error like "Expected:=". please see the code below. Please let me know where I am doing wrong. I am getting error in cmdCommand.Execute()

```
With rcdDNE.Fields
        .Append "RTN", adVarChar, 9
        .Append "AccountNbr", adVarChar, 17
        .Append "IndividualName", adVarChar, 22
        .Append "FirstName", adVarChar, 50
        .Append "MiddleName", adVarChar, 1
        .Append "LastName", adVarChar, 50
        .Append "Amount", adCurrency
    End With

    rcdDNE.Open
    intFileNbr = FreeFile(1)
    Open strFileName For Input As #intFileNbr Len = 95 ' Open file for input.
    Do While Not EOF(intFileNbr)
       Line Input #intFileNbr, strCurrentLine
       If Mid(strCurrentLine, 1, 1) = 6 Then
         strRoutingNbr = Mid(strCurrentLine, 4, 8)
         strAcct = Mid(strCurrentLine, 13, 17)
         strIndividualName = Trim(Mid(strCurrentLine, 55, 22))
         strAmount = Trim(Mid(strCurrentLine, 30, 10))
         strAmount = Left(strAmount, Len(strAmount) - 1)
         curAmount = CCur(strAmount)
       End If

       ' Add new record to temporary recordset
            With rcdDNE
                .AddNew
                .Fields![RTN] = strRoutingNbr
                .Fields![AccountNbr] = strAcct
                .Fields![IndividualName] = strIndividualName
                .Fields![Amount] = curAmount
                .Update
            End With

    Loop
    Close #intFileNbr

    frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "Formatting Names..."
    frmDNELoad.Refresh
    DoEvents

        ' Parse the IndividualName field
    rcdDNE.MoveFirst
    Do Until rcdDNE.EOF
        lngMidInitPos = 0
        lngParsePos1 = 0
        lngParsePos2 = 0
        lngParsePos3 = 0
        lngParsePos4 = 0
        lngParsePos5 = 0
        lngParsePos6 = 0
        strParseString = ""
        strParseFirstNm = ""
        strParseMidInit = ""
        strParseLastNam = ""

        strParseString = Trim(rcdDNE.Fields![IndividualName])
        ' Replace double spaces ("  ") with a single space (" ")
        lngPos = InStr(1, strParseString, "  ")
        Do While lngPos
            strParseString = Mid(strParseString, 1, lngPos - 1) & Mid(strParseString, lngPos + 1, Len(strParseString))
            lngPos = InStr(1, strParseString, "  ")
        Loop

        ' Locate positions of remaining spaces
        lngParsePos1 = InStr(1, strParseString, " ")
        If lngParsePos1 = 0 Then
            lngParsePos2 = 0
        Else
            lngParsePos2 = InStr(lngParsePos1 + 1, strParseString, " ")
        End If

        If lngParsePos2 = 0 Then
            lngParsePos3 = 0
        Else
            lngParsePos3 = InStr(lngParsePos2 + 1, strParseString, " ")
        End If
        If lngParsePos3 = 0 Then
            lngParsePos4 = 0
        Else
            lngParsePos4 = InStr(lngParsePos3 + 1, strParseString, " ")
        End If
        If lngParsePos4 = 0 Then
            lngParsePos5 = 0
        Else
            lngParsePos5 = InStr(lngParsePos4 + 1, strParseString, " ")
        End If
        If lngParsePos5 = 0 Then
            lngParsePos6 = 0
        Else
            lngParsePos6 = InStr(lngParsePos5 + 1, strParseString, " ")
        End If

        ' Determine if Middle initial is present
        If (lngParsePos3 - lngParsePos2) = 2 Then
            lngMidInitPos = lngParsePos2 + 1
            rcdDNE.Fields![MiddleName] = Mid(strParseString, lngMidInitPos, 1)
        ElseIf (lngParsePos4 - lngParsePos3) = 2 Then
            lngMidInitPos = lngParsePos3 + 1
            rcdDNE.Fields![MiddleName] = Mid(strParseString, lngMidInitPos, 1)
        ElseIf (lngParsePos5 - lngParsePos4) = 2 Then
            lngMidInitPos = lngParsePos4 + 1
            rcdDNE.Fields![MiddleName] = Mid(strParseString, lngMidInitPos, 1)
        ElseIf (lngParsePos6 - lngParsePos5) = 2 Then
            lngMidInitPos = lngParsePos5 + 1
            rcdDNE.Fields![MiddleName] = Mid(strParseString, lngMidInitPos, 1)
        ElseIf (lngParsePos2 - lngParsePos1) = 2 Then
            lngMidInitPos = lngParsePos1 + 1
            rcdDNE.Fields![MiddleName] = Mid(strParseString, lngMidInitPos, 1)
        End If

        ' If there is a middle initial, everything to the left of it goes into the
        ' first name field, and everything to the right of it goes into the last
        ' name field. If there is no middle initial, everything after the first space
        ' goes into the last name field.
        If lngMidInitPos <> 0 Then
            rcdDNE.Fields![FirstName] = Trim(Left(strParseString, lngMidInitPos - 1))
            rcdDNE.Fields![LastName] = Trim(Mid(strParseString, lngMidInitPos + 1, Len(strParseString)))
        Else
            rcdDNE.Fields![FirstName] = Trim(Left(strParseString, lngParsePos1))
            rcdDNE.Fields![LastName] = Trim(Mid(strParseString, lngParsePos1 + 1, Len(strParseString)))
        End If
        rcdDNE.Update
        rcdDNE.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' Write records to Database

    Call FindServerConnection_NoMsg

    Dim cmdCommand As New ADODB.Command
    If rcdDNE.EOF = False Then

    rcdDNE.MoveFirst

    cmdCommand.CommandText = "insert into DneFrc (RTN, AccountNbr, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Amount) values (RTN, AccountNbr, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Amount)"
    cmdCommand.Execute()
    rcdDNE.MoveNext
    Loop Until rcdDNE.EOF = True
```

Comment: i changed my cmdcommand.execute statement()   like this 

cmdCommand.CommandText = "insert into DneFrc (RTN, AccountNbr, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Amount) values ('" & .Fields![RTN] & "', '" & .Fields![AccountNbr] & "', '" & .Fields![FirstName] & "', '" & .Fields![MiddleName] & "', '" & .Fields![LastName] & "', '" & .Fields![Amount] & "')"

I am getting error like invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: The "flag for moderator attention" feature is for admin purposes only, not for getting answers.

Comment: You are not getting answers because you've posted loads of code *and* you've left out some important setup details. What is rcdDne? An ADO recordset? What query are you running to create it? It's too hard to read all that and guess the data types and the previous code.

Answer (score 1):

You state that the error is occurring in cmdCommand.Execute()

This is simply executing the value of CommandText.
It really has nothing to do with the previous code, which could be replaced in the example with a simple table of the data used, and a simple explanation of the expected states of the table(s), and the outcome

The original CommandText is obviously wrong because the values list comprises undeclared variables.

The changed values list won't work either unless you block the code using 'with rcdDNE' so you can use .Fields instead of rcdDNE.Fields.

I cut and pasted the string into notepad to discover the mix of ' and " which on first view look ok, except I would check this.

Also, think about the numeric and string values.
A good test would be to simply construct a value list with hard coded test values in it.
You could also assign the field values to variables and use these in your value list. This way you could test the actual value of each for validity prior to executing the statement.

You could also try executing the command directly in an SQL environment, rather than running your code each time.